# Subtraction of two dates to give age

Tags: linux, solaris, csh

I need to subtract two dates in the form 'yyyymmdd' (Study date - Date of birth) to find the age of a patient, how can I do this in C shell?

I've looked online but all I can find are bash & korn scripts, I'm not really familiar enough with either to change them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not so easy in csh, but you can do something like this:

```
% @ sec1 = `date -d '20050902' +'%s'`
% @ sec2 = `date -d '20090809' +'%s'`
% @ diffsec = `expr $sec2 - $sec1`
% @ age = `expr $diffsec / 365 / 24 / 3600`
% echo $age
3
```

Comment: Great, That looks perfectly good for my needs. Much appreciated.